# Pegar valor de um select

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de pegar o valor do select conforme for adicionando mais campos. Estou tentando pegar dessa forma, mas ele só me retorna o Pax, ou seja, sempre o primeiro valor, mesmo quando seleciono o Adulto ou outro valor do select.

```
<table border="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td  style="padding: 5px">
          <select name="TipoDocumento[]" class="form-control tipoPassageiro">
            <option>Pax</option>
            <option value="Adulto">Adulto</option>
            <option value="Adolescente entre 12 e 18 anos">Adolescente entre 12 e 18 anos</option>
            <option value="Criança entre 6 e 12 anos">Criança entre 6 e 12 anos</option>
            <option value="Criança de colo de até 6 anos">Criança de colo de até 6 anos</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      <td  style="padding: 5px"><input type="text" name="NomePAX[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome do pax" value=""></td>
      <td  style="padding: 5px">
        <select id="TipoDocumento" name="TipoDocumento[]" class="form-control">
          <option>Tipo de documento</option>
          <option value="Carteira de Identidade">Carteira de Identidade</option>
          <option value="Carteira Nacional de Habilitação">Carteira Nacional de Habilitação</option>
          <option value="Carteira de Trabalho">Carteira de Trabalho</option>
          <option value="Certidão de Nascimento">Certidão de Nascimento</option>
          <option value="Passaporte">Passaporte</option>
          <option value="Cédula de Identidade Estrangeira">Cédula de Identidade Estrangeira</option>
          <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td  style="padding: 5px">
         <input type="text" name="Documento[]" class="form-control" placeholder="RG da pessoa autorizada" value="">
      </td>
      <td  style="padding: 5px">
         <input type="text" name="OrgaoEmissor[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Órgão Emissor" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

JQuery

```
$(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
    var tipoPassageiro = $(".tipoPassageiro option:selected").val();
    alert(tipoPassageiro);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você tem mais de um elemento com a mesma classe `.tipoPassageiro` e usa o seletor `$(".tipoPassageiro option:selected").val()` sem especificar a posição, irá sempre pegar o valor do primeiro elemento com essa classe.

Se quer pegar o valor do último elemento da classe, acrescente `:last`:

```
$(".tipoPassageiro:last").val();
```

Não é necessário usar `option:selected`. O valor do `select` já é o `option` selecionado.

Comment: Show Sam. Na verdade estou tentando montar aquele outro post e precisava dessa resposta para começar a construir a outra resposta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Todas as queries do jQuery retornam uma lista de resultados, mesmo que você esteja procurando por apenas um elemento do DOM. Quando você usa `val()`, o jQuery presume que você procurou por apenas um elemento, e te retorna o valor do primeiro item da lista.

Como vários elementos possuem a classe `tipoPassageiro`, o jQuery só te retornará o valor do primeiro elemento encontrado com essa classe. Se você deseja diferenciá-los, dê um id diferente para cada um dos elementos que você criar, e faça a query por id.

Se não há a necessidade de diferenciá-los, você pode iterar sobre a lista de resultados com each:

```
$(".tipoPassageiro option:selected").each((i, e) => {
    alert(e.value);
});
```

Ou então gerar uma lista com os resultados usando map:

```
var listaResultados = $.map($(".tipoPassageiro option:selected"), (e) => e.value);
alert(listaResultados);
```